# hamburger toggler animation doesn't work immediately after refresh of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, navbar

hamburger toggler animation doesn't work immediately after i refresh the page, it starts working after i  hit it one time. the mainMenu appears without animation the first time i hit the openMenu. i dont understand how its possible working after the second time i hit it. there is something i am missing probably. why is this happening?

```js
const mainMenu = document.querySelector(".mainMenu");
const closeMenu = document.querySelector(".closeMenu");
const openMenu = document.querySelector(".openMenu");
openMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
    mainMenu.style.display = "flex";
    mainMenu.style.top = "0";
});
closeMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
    mainMenu.style.top = "-100%";
});
```

```css
.row .left {
  height: 98vh;
  background-color: #5a2a19;
}

.row .right {
  height: 98vh;
  background-color: #ff640b;
}

.row .right nav .openMenu {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row .right nav .mainMenu {
  background-color: #ff640b;
  height: 100vh;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-transition: top 1s ease;
  transition: top 1s ease;
  list-style: none;
}

.row .right nav .mainMenu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a2a19;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row .right nav .mainMenu li a:hover {
  color: #e6e8de;
}

.row .right nav .mainMenu .closeMenu {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row .right nav .mainMenu .icons i {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  color: #5a2a19;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row .right nav .mainMenu .bi-facebook:hover {
  color: #4267b2;
}

.row .right nav .mainMenu .bi-instagram:hover {
  color: #e1306c;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Bees cafe</title>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="js/index.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 left"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 right">
          <nav>
            <div class="openMenu"><i class="bi bi-list"></i></div>
            <ul class="mainMenu">
              <li><a href="#">lala</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">lala</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">lala</a></li>
              <div class="closeMenu"><i class="bi bi-x-lg"></i></div>
              <span class="icons">
                <i class="bi bi-facebook"></i>
                <i class="bi bi-instagram"></i>
              </span>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are setting `display` to `flex` when opening for `.mainMenu`, but never when closing, we might as well set it to `flex` by default. This fixes the initial problem, but causes the menu to be open by default, so we can fix this by adding the same styling we add when closing, to the initial css (setting `top: -100%;` in `.mainMenu`).

```js
const mainMenu = document.querySelector(".mainMenu");
const closeMenu = document.querySelector(".closeMenu");
const openMenu = document.querySelector(".openMenu");
openMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
    mainMenu.style.top = "0";
});
closeMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
    mainMenu.style.top = "-100%";
});
```

```css
.row .left {
  height: 98vh;
  background-color: #5a2a19;
}

.row .right {
  height: 98vh;
  background-color: #ff640b;
}

.row .right nav .openMenu {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row .right nav .mainMenu {
  background-color: #ff640b;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-transition: top 1s ease;
  transition: top 1s ease;
  list-style: none;
}

.row .right nav .mainMenu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a2a19;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row .right nav .mainMenu li a:hover {
  color: #e6e8de;
}

.row .right nav .mainMenu .closeMenu {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row .right nav .mainMenu .icons i {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  color: #5a2a19;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row .right nav .mainMenu .bi-facebook:hover {
  color: #4267b2;
}

.row .right nav .mainMenu .bi-instagram:hover {
  color: #e1306c;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Bees cafe</title>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="js/index.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 left"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 right">
          <nav>
            <div class="openMenu"><i class="bi bi-list"></i></div>
            <ul class="mainMenu">
              <li><a href="#">lala</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">lala</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">lala</a></li>
              <div class="closeMenu"><i class="bi bi-x-lg"></i></div>
              <span class="icons">
                <i class="bi bi-facebook"></i>
                <i class="bi bi-instagram"></i>
              </span>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```